# bcrypt error: Devise ruby 2.0 and rails 3.2.13

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems, bcrypt

Where i try to run the `bundle install` , I got the below error:

```
C:\Users\xxx\Documents\NetBeansProjects\githupbdcm\trunk>bundle exec rake
rake aborted!
incompatible library version - C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3
.1.1.rc1-x86-mingw32/lib/bcrypt_ext.so
C:/Users/xxx/Documents/NetBeansProjects/githupbdcm/trunk/config/application
.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Users/xxx/Documents/NetBeansProjects/githupbdcm/trunk/Rakefile:5:in `req
uire'
C:/Users/xxx/Documents/NetBeansProjects/githupbdcm/trunk/Rakefile:5:in `<to
p (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

My gem file looks like:

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.1.rc1', :require => 'bcrypt'
```

I have 3 versions of the gem:

```
C:\Users\xxx\Documents\NetBeansProjects\githupbdcm\trunk>gem uninstall bcrypt-ruby

Select gem to uninstall:
1. bcrypt-ruby-3.1.1-x86-mingw32
2. bcrypt-ruby-3.1.1
3. bcrypt-ruby-3.1.1.rc1-x86-mingw32
4. All versions
```

Still I got this error, Kindly help

with regards,
chandra

Answer (score 0):

Check your Rakefile. Line 5. Also, can you run the task using the `--trace` flag and post the results?

Comment: i changed my gemfile,  i added   gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.1', :require => 'bcrypt' and then gem 'devise', '3.0.0' . This works fine